# How can I deploy a nuxt.js app to Apache?

Tags: apache, deployment, nuxt.js

I started my own blog(static content) with nuxt.js. But I got some problems when I deploy the nuxt.js app to Apache.

I know it's better to deploy nuxt.js to Nginx, but I have no choice other than Apache ..  I did proxy setting for my nuxt.js app to connect with my domain. But Only home page works, the other pages show an invalid DNS error message.

**What I've done**

1. `npm nuxt generate` > `npm nuxt start` in my CLI
2. Proxy setting in httpd-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myname/projects"
    ProxyRequests OFF
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000
</VirtualHost>
```

3. When I browse my domain, landing page shows but the others don't.

- Clink Publications Page -> show invalid DNS error for "localhost:3000publications
- Image(jpg, png) files do not load.

How can I deploy my nuxt.js to Apache?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The problem with your mod_proxy configuration is that you are missing the trailing slash from the proxy URL, i.e. the two directives need to be:

   ```
      ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
   ```
2. However, if you have generated a static Nuxt site with `nuxt generate`, and need to serve it using Apache, then you do not need to run the Nuxt app with `nuxt start`. Instead, you can just serve the generated static files with Apache directly.

   Upload the contents of your Nuxt app's `dist` sub-directory to the Apache `DocumentRoot`, remove the proxy configuration directives, and that should be all that's needed.

Comment: @RWS Thanks for your big help! The trailing slash was the one that made invalid DNS errors :) and now I knew how to deploy static files !